# Finding Where Modules Are Coming From

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, template-hints

I am using a third-party theme called Porto.

It has a slider on the main screen, and I can't figure out which files are used in displaying it. Turning on backend template hints doesn't help located it. In fact, template hints show that it doesn't have a template of it's own. There are a few items on my homepage for which this is true.

I have searched the root directory via Visual Studio Code (my IDE) for every class and ID related this slider, and I still cannot find it. I have been trying for hours to figure out where this slider is being called from. Ideally, I would like to find out where in the XML it is being called, so that I can remove it and place something else in its place.

As a side note, why is it so terribly difficult to understand what is causing what in Magento, and isn't this painful for most developers?

[image]

Comment: You can try this: https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_TemplateHints shouldgive you somemor hints.

Comment: Hi @sv3n, is this only for Magento 1 - I see it has a "skin" folder? I am using Magento 2.

Answer (score 2):

Have you searched around for any mentions of "banner-slider"? Peeking at the Porto M2 theme demo now, and it looks like Owl Carousel gets added to whatever banner-slider id is there -- might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. I see a lot of XML files in app\code. I hesitate to make changes there, because I believe I should be in app\design when making front-end changes.

Also, even when I delete these various "demo".xml pages, and flush cache, I fail to see any changes.

Comment: If I were in your shoes, I'd probably create a custom theme that inherits the Porto theme and then make your overrides there. Then you'd probably need to create a cms_index_index.xml file and remove the slider block from there. Hmm. Man, if this wasn't a premium theme I'd download it and take a look for ou!

Comment: Thank you for spending the time to help. I have created a child theme already and am working off of it, as I do not want to mess around with the actual porto theme.

I cannot find where the slider is being generated. I was really hoping for an XML file that calls a template. I have found that structure in other places on the site. It's fairly straight-forward. As for this, I am at a complete loss.

Comment: Any chance you could toss everything on github or something?

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to follow the following steps.

1) Login To Admin

2) Navigate to System->Configuration.

3) change Current Configuration Scope to your website.

4) Navigate to Advanced->Developer which is available at the lower side of the page.

5) Under debug set Template Path Hints = yes and Add Block Names to Hints = yes and refresh the page to which you want to debug you will get a path for the phtml file and block file.

6) to find a block for ex Mage_Page_Block_Switch you need to move for the location app\code\core\Mage\Page\Block\Switch.php where Mage is the namespace / company name, Page is the module name and Switch is the block file name.

Hope this will help you.

[image]